# Derivation of ripple factor equation for a full-wave rectifier with filter

Tags: ripple, full-bridge

I'm trying to derive the ripple factor for a full wave rectifier with a filter.

This parameter is defined as the ratio of the root mean square (rms) value of the ripple voltage (Vr_rms) to the absolute value of the DC component of the output voltage:

γ =  Vr_rms / Vdc

I use the following plot with an assumption of |AB| = T/2.

[image]

First I want to write an expression for ripple rms voltage Vr_rms.

The ripple amplitude as seen in the plot is Vr. This can be approximated(using Taylor series expansion's first term for exponential decay) and given for full wave rectifier with a filter as:

Vr = |XY| = t/τ * Vm, and in this case t = T/2 and τ = R*C

Vr = Vm / (2*C*R*f) and rms value of a triangle wave is given as Vp/sqrt(3) so:

Vr_rms = Vm / (2*sqrt(3)xC*R*f)

Now I want to find the average DC voltage Vdc. This can be approximated as:

Vdc = Vm - (Vr/2)

This yields the ripple factor:

γ =  Vr_rms / Vdc

γ  = [Vm / (2*sqrt(3)xC*R*f) ] / [Vm - (Vr/2)]

γ  = [1 / (2*sqrt(3)xC*R*f) ] / [1 - (Vr/(2*Vm))] and since Vr/Vm = 1/(2*C*R*f)

γ = [1 / (2*sqrt(3)xC*R*f) ] / [1 - (1/(4*C*R*f))]

I'm stuck at this point I cannot progress and the texts give this factor as:

[image]

How is this derived? I cannot reach this..

Comment: If T=period of the rectified sine wave, then it seems clear from your plot that AB is not equal to T/2.  Note that T is a fixed value while Vr is a function of T and RC. Thus as RC varies, Vr will vary, and hence AB will also vary.

Comment: Noo AB is taken T/2 because ripple is assumed very small. Read the texts. It is an approximation assumes RC>>T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RMS value of a triangle wave is its peak value/sqrt(3).  In your case the peak value of the triangle wave is Vr/2, not Vr which is the peak-to-peak value. This correction will produce a factor of 4 in your final result instead of 2.  If you then make the approximation that RC>>T, then CRf>>1.  With that approximation, the denominator in your final equation can be approximated as 1 since 1/(4CRf)<<1.  The result is that your final equation reduces to the desired result.

Comment: Your argument seems very correct. I didn't notice that. Please see my previous question I had a similar issue of reaching an equation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334871/a-question-about-ripple-factor-in-a-bridge-rectifier

Comment: It's the same idea.  In general, 1/(1+x) can be approximated by 1-x if x<<1.  In your case, x=1/4CRf.  Since CRf>>1, x<<1.  Thus the 2 results are the same.